# Reverse USB tethering in 2022?

Tags: networking, usb, android, tethering, reverse-tethering

I'm trying to let my Android phone access internet over a host computer, via a USB cable. The solutions that I can find all seems to require a rooted phone.

However, all current generation Android phones supports USB network tethering. Turning on USB tethering would let the phone present itself as a RNDIS USB network adapter, which automatically puts the host computer and the phone into one LAN.

In this scenario, theoretically it's possible to reverse tether the host computer's internet connection to the phone by turning the host computer into a software router.

So the question is, how to configure the host (and the phone) for that?

(I have Windows11 and Ubuntu dual boot so solutions for either OS works would work for me.)

Answer (score 6):

Yes!, it's possible, there a program called [**gnirehtet**](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet) which allows you to give internet access to you android smartphone via USB as if it were ethernet. They offer a **Java** and a **Rust** version.

What this program does is to install an APK of the same program and then configure a VPN on your android phone when you run the command `gnirehtet run` in the console or cmd.